# warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default] in c

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, comparison

I want to check whether the user input contains only digits or not. So, I use the following code:

```
for(i = 0; argv[1][i] != NULL; i++)
    if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
    {
        printf("Error");
        return -1;
    }
```

It works well but I got this warning:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

since `argv[1][i]` is an Integer and `NULL` is a pointer. How can I avoid such warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NULL` is not the same as the null-terminator character.  You should use `'\0'` instead.

Answer (score 3):

argv[1][i] is a char, just compare it with '\0' or 0, it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For a character comparison, this can be used (or just 0 for that matter);

```
for(i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
```