# C comparing char to "\n" warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, pointers, cc

I have the following part of C code:

```
char c;
int n = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
    if (c == "\n"){
        n++;
    }
}
```

during compilation, compiler tells me

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

The thing is that if to substitute `"\n"` with `'\n'` there are no warnings at all.
Can anyone explain me the reason? Another strange thing is that I am not using pointers at all.

I am aware of the following questions

- [warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default] in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435432/warning-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer-enabled-by-default-in-c)
- [warning: comparison between pointer and integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654685/warning-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer-in-c)

but in my opinion they are unrelated to my question.

PS. If instead of `char c` there will be `int c` there will be still warning.

Comment: To detect `EOF` `c` needs to be defined a s`int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `'\n'` is called a **character** literal and is a scalar integer type.
- `"\n"` is called a **string** literal and is an array type. Note that arrays decay to pointers and so that's why you're getting that error.

This may help you understand:

```
// analogous to using '\n'
char c;
int n = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
    int comparison_value = 10;      // 10 is \n in ascii encoding
    if (c == comparison_value){
        n++;
    }
}

// analogous to using "\n"
char c;
int n = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
    int comparison_value[1] = {10}; // 10 is \n in ascii encoding
    if (c == comparison_value){     // error
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on @Pubby, when you use '\n' this ends up being the same type as c in the comparison, which gets rid of the comparison type mismatch.

Comment: @DietrichEpp but he is getting that warning when doing this comparison c == "\n"

Comment: The difference between it being `char` or `int` is irrelevant to his error.

Comment: getchar() returns int. Don't use char here otherwise the comparison with EOF may fail (char may be unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

Basically '\n' is a literal expression that evaluates to a char.
"\n" is a literal expression that evaluates to a pointer. So by using this expression, you are effectively using a pointer.

The pointer in question is pointing to a region of memory that contains an array of characters (\n in this case) followed by a termination character that tells code where the array ends.

Hope that helps?