# error: comparision between pointer and integer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
char c;
char a[19][100];
int i=0;
int j=0;

while((c=fgetc(stdin))!=EOF)
{
  if(c!=" ")
  {
    a[i][j]=c;
    j++;
   }
   if(c==" "||c=='\n')
{
   a[i][j]='\0';
   i++;
   j=0;
    }
 }
 for(j=0;j<i;j++)
printf("%s \n",a[j]);
}
```

the error that i get is

```
   15.c:12:5: warning: comparison between pointer and integer[enabled       by   default]

 if(c!=" ")
     ^

15.c:17:5: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by   default]

if(c==" "||c=='\n')
```

Comment: `" "` is used for string (i.e, `char *`). Use `' '` for `char`.

Comment: Do you not see the inconsistency between `" "` and `'\n'`?

Comment: noticed  it  thanks for the help

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/13041701/694576. As not referring to the `EOF` issue I do not consider it a real duplicate.

Comment: `c` should be `int` if you want to handle EOF case correctly.

Comment: The compiler allocates `" "` as a null-terminated string (containing 2 characters - the space character and the null character) at a constant memory address within the executable image (typically in the RO data-section, since this string is read-only). Then, it translates the expression `c!=" "` into `c!=<the_memory_address>`. But while the size of `c` is that of a single character (typically 1 byte), the size of a memory address is larger (typically 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your platform). This is why you get a compilation warning - the compiler has to truncate the larger operand.

Answer (score 2):

`c` is defined to be a `char` and `" "` is a "string" literal, which in C is implemtned as an array of `char`s, which in turn decays to a pointer to it's 1st element, that is  a `char *`.

To fix this compare `c` to a `char`.

```
if (c != ' ')  /* Use ' to code a char literal, use " to code a string literal. "/
```

---

Also as you assign the result of [`fgetc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html) to `c` and test `c` against `EOF` (which typically is `-1`) make `c` an `int`, that is make it the type `fgetc()` returns.

Answer (score -1):

You compare `char` with `char *`. You can not do it, and set `c` to be `signed char` because it need to store `EOF`. It depends on compiler does `char` will `signed` or `unsigned`, so you can't know.
It need to be like this:

```
if(c!= ' ')
  {
    a[i][j]=c;
    j++;
   }
```

Comment: Using `signed char` for `c` would make the program fail when reading a `0xff`.

Comment: I write text, and now if OP user read it, user will go  to look  what is signed and what is unsigned , and what is scope for both. I think that s/he need char for print values in scope < 127 (normal characters like a,b,c...) , and in that case c can be signed char .

Comment: Using a `signed char` will work for 255 out of 256 possible characters. It ill fail for the character with the value `0xff`. Using an `int` it will work for **all** characters that is 256 out of 256.

Comment: You right. I just write, example for signed variable, OP user, to get know that there is signed and unsigned,  to make vision that he can use just CHAR  to handle EOF ,  but don't take to compiler to choose does it signed or unsigned.

Comment: @alk Why OP need 0xff ?

Comment: In case the tool would process for example binary data, when used with I/O redirection: `a.out <input >outout`